# how to use session in expressjs view file (.pug)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, pug

i have tried to use session variable in expressJs view file(.pug) but its not directly used.

i was also tried `locals` but its clear on page reload or redirect

my code is below

```
userLogin(data.email,data.password).then(function(result) {
          if(result){
            req.session.login = true; //use in view file
            res.redirect('products');
          }else{
            res.render('login',{msg:'Invalid Creadential !'})
          }
      });
```

and tried code in `.pug` file

```
 if(login)
          li
            a(href='logout') Logout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [express-dynamic-helpers-patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-dynamic-helpers-patch), then you can create a `dynamicHelper` as follows :

```
require('express-dynamic-helpers-patch')(app);
app.dynamicHelpers({
session: function (req, res) {
    return req.session;
    }
});
```

then in your view you can acess `session` object directly :

```
if(session.login)
      li
        a(href='logout') Logout
```